# What are 0, 1, . , * in this Yii2 documentation image

Tags: php, yii2

From the doc of Yii

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-workflow.html#application-structure

[image]

What this means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are different types of **multiplicity** in UML diagrams.

```
Multiplicity Option Cardinality
0..0         0      Collection must be empty
0..1                No instances or one instance
1..1         1      Exactly one instance
0..*         *      Zero or more instances
1..*                At least one instance
5..5         5      Exactly 5 instances
m..n                At least m but no more than n instances
```

See more information [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is [UML class diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram). And 0..* means relation where main member may have from 0 to infinity children. For example "application" may have 0 or more "modules", but "entry script" can have only one "application"